# Getting Internal Server Error on pgSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, import

Im tryingto import data from windows CSV (comma delimiter) file into pgSQL faxtest1 table, but I keep getting error saying "The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."

The following is my code:

```
COPY faxtest1 
   FROM 'C:‪\Users\David\Desktop\test3.csv' 
   WITH DELIMITER AS ',' CSV ;
```

The CSV file is like:

```
Status,Fax ID
Fax to Email,2104
Fax to Email,2108
```

Comment: the table contains 2 columns: status with char(25) and id with integer

Comment: What program/application do you use to import?

Comment: pgsql import option, there is an option  "import/export"  if you right-click on the table in pgsql

Comment: This one: http://pgsql.navicat.com/ ?

Comment: internal server error is an http error, which Pgsql doesn't speak.  What software are you using?

Comment: pgadmin4 and excel for csv

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug of pg admin 4, hope they will fix it in the future.

Comment: Could you add some link to the bug?

Answer (score 0):

In version 14, in the Import/Export data function, there are 2 columns, "Options" and "Columns." Try manually select the columns one at time, separated by a comma. See if this would by pass the error.

It worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31872772)